# What does "aller du plaidoyer" mean

Tags: traduction

On the wikipedia page for multiculturalisme it says « Le multiculturalisme...fait référence à...des politique diverses qui peuvent aller du plaidoyer d'un respect des diverses cultures d'une société, à des politiques de promotion...». How do I translate *aller du plaidoyer* because DeepL says it means "go from advocacy" but that seems very literal so I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't directly ask about a French to English translation because it is off topic in FSE. Better to ask what exactly is meant if you are unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't translate "aller du plaidoyer" on its own. The expression you're looking for is:

> Aller de A à B

It means "*to range from A to B*", "*to include anything for A to B*". Here it means:

> Multiculturalism refers to various policies, ranging from pleas for a respect for the various cultures of a society, to policies promoting [...]

---

If you want to mention more than two things, a common variation of that expression is:

> Aller de A à B, en passant par C, D et E

Or sometimes

> Aller de A, à B, à C

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the sentence you need to cut it down properly :

**Aller de**  [quelque chose] **à** [autre chose]
*To go from* [*something/somewhere*] *to* [*something else/somewhere else*]

**Aller du** [plaidoyer d'un respect des diverses cultures d'une société] **à** [des politiques de promotion].

Then you need to understand these parts:

[Plaidoyer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plaidoyer) d'un respect des diverses cultures d'une société.
[Politiques](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/politique) de promotion.

Personally in this case I would translate *plaidoyer* by "plea (in favour of...)" and *politiques* by "strategies".